# How can you work out the probability of something if every test has given the same result?

Tags: statistics

If I believe both $X$ and $\lnot X$ are possible, and I test it 100 times and get $\lnot X$ 100 times, what is the probability of $X$? Naively it seems that the probability of $X$, i.e. $P(X)$, should be $0$, but the next test could be $X$ instead of $\lnot X$, so intuitively it seems that $P(X)$ could get ever closer to $0$ but never quite reach it.

I'm also thinking that standard deviations should come into it, so there should probably be a range of $0$ to what?

How do you calculate $P(X)$ given that each of that $n$ tests has given $\lnot X$?

Comment: I believe you can consider the geometric distribution for this case. Assuming the probability for $X$ is $p$ and $q=1-p$, the probability of no successes in $n$ trials (as in measuring $X$) is given by $q^n$.

Comment: There's not enough information to answer the question. You need the prior probabilities, i.e. you need to specify how likely you considered $X$ and $\neg X$ before you conducted the test. (For instance, absent further information, you may have considered them equally likely.) Probability theory can only tell you how to update those probabilities. (Or you may have intended to ask about frequentist hypothesis testing. In that framework, you can't calculate a probability $P(X)$; you can only calculate the probability of falsely rejecting $X$ under the assumption that $X$ is true.)

Comment: @joriki If I assumed that $P(X)$ had to be within one standard deviation, how would I calculate it?

Comment: @CJDennis: Did you read what I wrote?

Comment: The [rule of three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(statistics)) can give you an approach to finding a confidence interval for the value of $P(X)$ in such an extreme case - there are other approaches.  In your example of $100$ failures, it would suggest a $95\%$ confidence interval of $[0,0.03]$ and this would narrow as you observed more failures.